# Poner auto-incremento en campos agregados a la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola a todos espero y me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente problema en mi base de datos necesito que al momento de agregar una fila la siguiente sea consecutiva 1,2,3++, ya tengo el `id` como `primarykey` y `autoincrement` pero me toma el id de otra tabla de un usuario que agrega la linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En idViaje necesito que sea 1 y así sucesivamente

NOTA: Si se puede 0001 mucho mejor

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $razonSocial = $_POST["razonsocial"];
    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $cliente = $_POST["Cliente"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];
    $moneda = $_POST["moneda"];
    $mercancia = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $importe = $_POST["importe"];
    $tipoOperacion = $_POST["TipoOperacion"];
    $fechaAlta = $_POST["FechaAlta"];
    $detalles = $_POST["detalles"];
    $tipoTransporte = $_POST["TipoTransporte"];
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["FechaSalida"];
    $fechaLlegada = $_POST["FechaLlegada"];
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $porigen = $_POST["porigen"];
    $eorigen = $_POST["eorigen"];
    $corigen = $_POST["corigen"];
    $pdestino = $_POST["pdestino"];
    $edestino = $_POST["edestino"];
    $cdestino = $_POST["cdestino"];
    $coberturas = $_POST["Coberturas"];
    $poliza = $_POST["poliza"];
    $cuota = $_POST["cuota"];
    $prima = $_POST["prima"];
    $gastosexp = $_POST["gastosexp"];
    $iva = $_POST["iva"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];
    
        
    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';
  
    }else{
       query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, Coberturas, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total) VALUES ('".$idCliente."','".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."', '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', '".$mercancia."', '".$importe."', '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', '".$detalles."', '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."', '".$folio."','".$porigen."','".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."', '".$pdestino."', '".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$coberturas."', '".$poliza."', '".$cuota."', '".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')");
       
}
}
?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form id="nclientes" name="nclientes" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Datos del Asegurado</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon Social</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input name="razonsocial" type="text"  autocomplete="off" required title="Completar campo" class="typeahead_2 form-control" <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo 'value="'. $_COOKIE["usuario"] . '" disabled';
}
?> />
                                        <input id="idCliente" name="idCliente" type="hidden" value="<?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo $_COOKIE["idUsuario"];
}
?>" />
```

Comment: Qué gestor de base de datos usas? No entiendo a qué te refieres con " pero me toma el id de otra tabla de un usuario que agrega la linea", podrías explicarte?

Comment: Uso phpmyadmin, tengo una tabla de clientes en los cuales esos si se guardan con el id en incremento y ese cliente con id 203 agrego informacion en la tabla merca pero me toma el idCliente como idViaje como se ve en la imagen

Comment: Para que le puedas anteponer 000 a un campo tendrías que crearlo como varchar.

Comment: Mi pregunta ya se resolvio, pero me interesa eso del 000 antes del 1 como podria hacer el varchar ¿tendria que agregar una columna nueva en la base de datos o solo modificar el codigo?

Comment: Supongo que en php debe haber alguna forma de crear una "máscara" para el campo, para que, aunque en la base de datos se guarde como número, al mostrarla en pantalla se le pongan todos los 000 que quieras al frente... Además, si se cambia a varchar el campo, ya no podrá ser autoincrementable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu *query* tienes esto:

```
query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, 
importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, 
FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, 
Coberturas, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total) VALUES 
('".$idCliente."','".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."', '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', 
'".$mercancia."', '".$importe."', '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', 
'".$detalles."', '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."', 
'".$folio."','".$porigen."','".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."', '".$pdestino."', 
'".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$coberturas."', '".$poliza."', '".$cuota."', 
'".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')");
```

Donde en `VALUES`tienes dos veces `$idCliente` `VALUES ('".$idCliente."','".$idCliente."',` haciendo el primero a tu `idViaje` y el segundo a `idCliente` (el segundo esta bien).

Si en tu base de datos ya tienes idViaje como `AUTO_INCREMENT` deberias poner como valor a `idViaje` `DEFAULT`

Tu *query* quedaría así:

```
query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, 
importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, 
FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, 
Coberturas, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total) VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."', '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', 
'".$mercancia."', '".$importe."', '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', 
'".$detalles."', '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."', 
'".$folio."','".$porigen."','".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."', '".$pdestino."', 
'".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$coberturas."', '".$poliza."', '".$cuota."', 
'".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')");
```

Comment: Lo que no se es: mysql permite insertar datos manualmente en un campo autoincrementable? SQL server no me lo permite... tal vez también le haga falta crear el `idViaje` como incrementable...

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te haya servido!

Answer (score 0):

Te está tomando `idCliente` porque es lo que le está enviando:

```
query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente...  
VALUES ('".$idCliente."','".$idCliente."',
```

si tu `idViaje` es autoincremental no es necesario que lo envíes.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias